# I got response from client and there is many data (many boats) and from that string i want to fetch only one boat on server

Tags: c#, server, client, response

Client side:

```
 $("#gumb").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/VratiPoruku",
                success: function (results) {
                    console.log(results);
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult VratiPoruku()
{

    string serviceUrl = string.Format("http://boatsearch.bbuss.boatbooker.net/api/boat/search/perform/?offset=20&count=20", offset, count, DateTime.Now);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
    request.Headers["ws-auth"] = "eres";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;
    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        object ObjectList = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(responseText);
    }

    return View();
}
```

This is response that is want:
[{"Boat":{"ID":"23c96e77-a201-41fe-875e-034c278d915f","Name":"-","ModelID":"44fa3875-449a-443a-9e7e-4726f587d737","ModelName":"Dufour 34 (2 cab)","BrandID":"f2797762-5d98-4270-b9aa-4c05edbd4dd9","BrandName":"Dufour","TypeID":1,"BuildYear":2004,"YearOfLastReconstruction":null,"BerthsBasic":"4","BerthsMax":"6","BerthsStr":"4+2","CabinsBasic":"2","CabinsMax":"2","CabinsStr":"2","ToiletsBasic":"1","ToiletsMax":"1","ToiletsStr":"1","HullLength":null,"OverallLength":null,"LengthOfWaterline":9.1300,"BeamLength":3.4800,"Draft":1.5000,"Ballast":null,"WaterCapacity":265.0,"FuelCapacity":90.0,"Weight":null,"Engine":"19 HP","RealTimeAvailable":true,"BoatImages":ObjectID=1358&DocumentID=172300&nodisposition=true"}],"Mappings":null},"Bases":[{"ID":"d8903a3d-c979-4138-a02f-5ee6c31c47a5","Name":"Kos Marina","IsPrimary":true,"CountryId":"8e8ffeac-4239-44d5-9612-b418b842f084","LocationId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Areas":[{"Id":"f75fdf3c-47e1-45c4-8f56-d28560f5bed1","Name":"{\"EN\":\"Dodecanese\",\"DE\":\"Dodekanes\",\"FR\":\"Dod??can??se\",\"HR\":\"Dodekanez\",\"CS\":\"Dodekan??s\",\"HU\":\"Dodekan??szosz\",\"IT\":\"Dodecanese\",\"NL\":null,\"ES\":\"Dodecaneso\",\"NO\":null,\"PL\":\"Dodekanez\",\"RU\":\"??????????????????\",\"SK\":\"Dodekan??z\",\"SL\":null,\"SV\":\"Dodecanese\",\"EL\":null}"}]}]

Comment: I am really new in programming so if i have many mistakes, sorry

Comment: What is the response of the service look like?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya  I got 20 boats, and i have to take one from those 20.

Comment: What is  the criteria for selecting one boat? The first one? The latest one? The oldest one? The last one? Can you share the JSON response which you are getting from the service? that would help us to provide more suitable solution to your problem.

Comment: The response  you posted is of only one boat? or it is the entire responseText you are getting from the service?

Comment: There is no criteria for now, i can choose which ever i want.

Comment: That is only one boat

Comment: And in response there are 20 boat

Comment: I am not able to figure out the exact structure of the Boat object from the JSON. But the simple solution would be to create a class for Boat with the all the properties and then deseiralize the response text to an array of Boat class objects and take the first object from that array. Can you share portion of the start of the responseText until `[{"Boat":{"ID":` ?

Comment: {"RequestTimestamp":"2017-02-23T15:55:51.7848631+01:00","ResponseData":{"TotalResults":10732,"Results":